# Get the pixels color from the picture?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to put in the array all the pixels that the picture has.

To get something like this:

```
($FFFFFF, $FFFFF0, $F2FF4F ..................)
```

Where do I start? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Bitmap` [`getPixels()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is the way to go.